# Google+ auto backup jams up my WiFi network

Tags: wi-fi, backup, google-backup, bandwidth

For months I tried to track down a ping issue (high ping; disconnect & reconnect my router; low ping for about 20 minutes; high ping again). Turns out, thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/559819/alternating-low-and-high-ping-times-on-adsl-line), it was the Google+ auto backup feature (that, for some reason, seems to kick in several minutes *after* it gets a connection).

The Google+ auto backup feature is enabled on my phone. It is configured to upload in "standard size" (not "full size"). Also, it is set to only upload if charging and if on WiFi.

During backup, the ping time (from my laptop, but the same applies from the router's admin page) goes up to over 7000 ms, see:
[image: high ping]

If I disconnect my phone from WiFi, the ping time goes down to about 50 ms.

What can I do to avoid this from happening? I tried to search for some way to set *WiFi* bandwidth limits for a specific app, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Couldn't you just wait for it to finish?

Comment: @DanHulme I [don't have](http://www.speedtest.net/result/3726287708.png) a very fast connection, letting the backup finish would mean not being able to browse nor to work (I use SSH a lot) for hours.

Comment: Leaving it overnight would seem like a better alternative than prolonging the pain by making the upload slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to put a firewall between your phone and the router with these apps and block Google+, then when you don't use the internet (for example at night) enable it

- [No root needed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall)
- [No root needed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall&hl=en)
- [Root needed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.firewall&hl=en)